# AndroidViewClient - NullPointerException

Tags: monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I'm trying to make a script using MonkeyRunner & AndroidViewClient to test my own application.

I set the all environment variables in my Mac OS X. Of course, I can test my android application with a terminal command like './monkeyrunner test_script.py' and perform normally.

However, when I use the same script in Xcode, I got 'Couldn't connect to (Project path) : java.lang.NullPointerException' message.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest **AndroidViewClient 4.x.x** doesn't use `monkeyrunner` nor `java`, only `python`.
You should upgrade your scripts, unless you are depending on some of the very few functionality that was not ported yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could get some sleep.